# Find the instance name in management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, instance, ssms

How do I do in order to find and locate the current name of the active instance in SQL server 2008's SSMS?

My hostname is SAKURA-PC.
In my client I have two instance named MSSQLSERVER2008 and MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: Do you mean when you are in the new query window?

Answer (score 3):

`select @@ServerName`  in query analyser gives you server\instance.

Comment: If I do it, then I get the value "SAKURA-PC" that is not the same with the name of the active instance.

Comment: It means that you are connected to the default instance (MSSQLSERVER), not to the named one. From SSMS try to make a connection to SAKURA-PC\MSSQLSERVER2008 and issue the same "select @@servername" command.

Comment: Is it possible to see in the SSMS's screen when making the connection to MSSQLSERVER2008? Would like it to see it from my own eyes?